# A donkey does not know what kind of fruit persimmon is

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

The above-mentioned idiom comes from my native language. We use it when we are referring to a person ( often tasteless and unsophisticated one ) who finds it hard to  appreciate a good thing or does not understand the ( aesthetic ) value of something. More or less similar expression in English I have found is this - **"Caviar to the general"** but it does not fully convey the same meaning. Is there an idiom or expression in English which would carry the same meaning ?

> Yesterday we were talking about food and do you know what John said ? He said that he preferred fast food restaurants over expensive ones. Well, A donkey does not know what kind of fruit persimmon is.

Answer (score 4):

Try "pearls before the swine"

https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/pearls-before-swine.html

Items of quality offered to those who aren't cultured enough to appreciate them.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

**wouldn't know (something) if it hit (one) in the face**: Is too oblivious or ignorant to realize or recognize a very obvious thing. *You're no expert. You wouldn't know a Rembrandt if it hit you in the face. Tim's not much of a scout. He wouldn't know promising talent if it hit him in the face.*

> He wouldn't know good food if it hit him in the face.

But your original, translated literally to English, is so much better (the persimmon is my favorite fruit).  I suggest sticking with that.

Answer (score 1):

He is a philistine -

OED:

> 3. In extended use (now usually philistine). An uneducated or unenlightened person; one perceived to be indifferent or hostile to art or culture, or whose interests and tastes are commonplace or material; a person who is not a connoisseur.
>
> 1977   Times 8 Feb. 17/1   *The philistines would be foolish to regard aid for the arts merely as a perk provided by all for the esoteric pursuits of the few.*
>
> 2000   Sunday Times (Johannesburg) (Electronic ed.) 2 Jan.   *French chefs were imported [to Johannesburg] to lavish their talents on the culinary Philistines of the very young city.*

Answer (score 0):

There is the idiom/proverb "**There's no accounting for taste**". It can be overused, but it is still appropriately useful when *bad taste* rears its ugly head.

> Yesterday we were talking about food and do you know what John said ?
>   He said that he preferred fast food restaurants over expensive ones.
>   Well, ***There's no accounting for taste***.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/there%27s+no+accounting+for+taste